# Gettext not translating PHP in Debian 10

Tags: php, gettext

I'm trying to localize my website, it is located in a VPS running LEMP Debian 10 (PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1). I have spent the day troubleshooting why it's not working with no success.

My project has the following structure:

```
MY_PROJECT_NAME
   - locale
       - en_GB
            LC_MESSAGES
               en_GB.mo
               en_GB.po
       - es_ES
            LC_MESSAGES
               es_ES.mo
               es_ES.po
   - index.php
```

The file index.php has the following code:

```php
<?php

session_start();
$language = "es_ES";

if (isset($_GET['language']))
{
    $language = $_GET['language'];
}

putenv("LANG=" . $language);
putenv("LC_ALL={$language}");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

$domain = $language;
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale/");
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

var_dump( file_exists("./locale/$language/LC_MESSAGES/$language.mo" ) ); //bool(true) if exists
echo ('<br/>');
echo $language; //output the lang name
echo ('<br/>');
echo gettext('hello'); //text to be translated

?>
```

The content of file es_ES.po is as follows:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2021-05-28 00:19-0500\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2021-05-28 01:54-0500\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.4.3\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: es_ES\n"

msgid "hello"
msgstr "Hola mundo"
```

and the file en_GB.po has the following content:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2021-05-28 00:16-0500\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2021-05-28 01:54-0500\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.4.3\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: en_GB\n"

msgid "hello"
msgstr "Hello word"
```

Both files has been compiled with POedit, to generate the correct .mo files.

Also, i have added the locales to the system via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. The output of the command `locale -a` is the following:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
es_ES.utf8
it_IT.utf8
ja_JP.utf8
POSIX
pt_BR.utf8
```

Whenever i run the php code to check if the translation works:
`index.php?language=en_GB`
`index.php?language=es_ES`

I get the output:

```
bool(true)
en_GB
hello
```

and

```
bool(true)
es_ES
hello
```

Respectively. What am i missing? There is no error in the logs, i have rebooted the server to makie sure it's not a cache issue, also i have tried several variants of the index.php configurations with no success.

Comment: `setlocale` will return the locale it has set, or false if none could be selected. Can you check what that function returns and post the value here. It will help to determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: I just checked by running "setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
print(strftime("%A %e %B %Y", time()));"  and it had no effect (the localized date was not set), however i tried running "setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");
print(strftime("%A %e %B %Y", time()));" and the localized date was set correctly this time.

Comment: @mario, it was a mistake, the folder "locale" is lowercase.

Comment: @Arnold I believe the locale is not being set by the code. I appended the line `echo setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);` after the last line in the index.php file, and it comes out empty when i run the file. However if i run `index.php.php?language=es_ES.UTF-8`, the line "
es_ES.UTF-8" appears at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing additional languages with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

The locale `en_GB.utf8` was not set when `en_GB` was requested by the script.

There is no plain `en_GB` in debian's `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` screen, the needed locale is shown as `en_GB ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion is that you're using a dynamic domain, based on the language, while the domain is fixed and represents the filename of the translation.

So first of all, reorganise your files as follows

```
MY_PROJECT_NAME
   - locale
       - en_GB
            LC_MESSAGES
               messages.mo
               messages.po
       - es_ES
            LC_MESSAGES
               messages.mo
               messages.po
   - index.php
```

Once the files are renamed correctly, then you can set your $domain to `messages` instead of the language

```
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale/");
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
```

This should fix your issue. Also double check that your paths are correct, and depending on how you call your index.php file, you might want to switch from the relative path `./locale/` to using `__DIR__`

Comment: I wanted to use dynamic domain because i will be creating several translations, and having the same name for all the languages could be confusing for me. The line `var_dump( file_exists("./locale/$language/LC_MESSAGES/$language.mo" ) ); `  checks if the .mo files are present and found by the code. Still i will test your code to check if it works, thanks.